# Open URL with Safari no matter what system browser is set to

Tags: safari, nsworkspace, launch-services

In my objective-c program, I need to open a URL in Safari no matter what the system's default browser is. That means that this won't work, because it could launch Firefox or whatever other browser:

```
NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
[ws openURL: url];
```

I think I'm close with this:

```
[ws launchAppWithBundleIdentifier: @"com.apple.Safari"
                          options: NSWorkspaceLaunchWithoutActivation
   additionalEventParamDescriptor: NULL
                 launchIdentifier: nil];
```

only need to figure out how to pass in the URL as parameter... Is there an easier way?

Thanks!

*Update:* The following code launches Safari with the URL I want, but Safari terminates right away! Any ideas why this is?

```
NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
[ws openURLs: urls withAppBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari" 
     options: NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault
additionalEventParamDescriptor: NULL
launchIdentifiers: NULL];
```

I observed the same behavior with `LSOpenFromURLSpec`. If a Safari instance is running, it works fine. If no Safari instance was running, it starts a new one and terminates it right away.

*Update 2:* Safari only crashes for web sites that have Flash embedded. With the code above, I can open google.com just fine, however Safari crashes for a YouTube video, for example.

Comment: 'system("Safari URL")' or something similar doesn't work?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I tried this from the Terminal. Safari starts up, but treats the URL as local file and thus can't find it.

Comment: This got me close, but if Safari is not already running, it opens and terminates right away. No error reported:

  NSString *safariFullPath = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] fullPathForApplication:@"Safari"];
    
    NSArray* urls = [ NSArray arrayWithObject: url];
    
    LSLaunchURLSpec urlSpec;
    urlSpec.appURL = (CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:safariFullPath];
    urlSpec.itemURLs = ( CFArrayRef )urls;
    urlSpec.passThruParams = NULL;
    urlSpec.launchFlags = kLSLaunchAsync;
    urlSpec.asyncRefCon = NULL;

  OSStatus status = LSOpenFromURLSpec( &urlSpec, NULL  );

Comment: @Mark This throws - +[__NSCFConstantString baseURL]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x7fff9805b1b8

Answer (score 5):

Try the `OpenURLs` method from [`NSWorkspace`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
- (BOOL) openURLs:(NSArray *)urls
         withAppBundleIdentifier:(NSString *)bundleIdentifier
         options:(NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions)options
         additionalEventParamDescriptor:(NSAppleEventDescriptor *)descriptor
         launchIdentifiers:(NSArray **)identifiers
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this to open the url in the default browser...

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com/"];
if( ![[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:url] )
    NSLog(@"Failed to open url: %@",[url description]);
```

Comment: While this opens an URL I think it does not really answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

The two options I listed above actually work for websites that don't include Flash movies.

The crash I described seems to be a bug that can even be reproduced with a single Applescript. I opened a separate question for this ([AppleScript to open URL in Safari crashes for Flash-based websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971924/applescript-to-open-url-in-safari-crashes-for-flash-based-websites))

For the record, the answer to my question is to either use `LSOpenFromURLSpec` or this code:

```
NSWorkspace * ws = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace];
[ws openURLs: urls withAppBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari" 
  options: NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault
  additionalEventParamDescriptor: NULL
  launchIdentifiers: NULL];
```

Comment: Hy Mark, if this solved your problem now. You may want to mark your (or another one) as the answer to your question. If you experience a crash I think this would be another issue then.

Comment: How do it on iOS? NSWorkspace available just for macOS 10.0+

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an AppKit framework. Just implement this.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"];    

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```