# Open URL In Safari

Tags: objective-c, macos, safari

In objective c in mac development, how do i open a url in safari?
I know how to in iPhone dev but not in Mac Dev

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Open URL with Safari no matter what system browser is set to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965615/open-url-with-safari-no-matter-what-system-browser-is-set-to)

Comment: The linked question has no accepted answer and most of the comments are from the OP. This doesn't seem like an acceptable resolution.

Comment: @edwin so I should delete the answer?

Comment: Oh, I can't delete the accepted answer.