# How to open a url in safari even if my default browser is not Safari using Swift in macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, safari

I am trying to open a url in Safari even if my default browser is set to Google Chrome. How do I do that? I am using the following code, but it opens the url in the default browser only.

```
let requiredURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com)")!
NSWorkspace.shared.open(requiredURL)
```

Do I have to use the following function:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(urls: [URL], withApplicationAt: URL, options: NSWorkspace.LaunchOptions, configuration: [NSWorkspace.LaunchConfigurationKey : Any])
```

If so, how do I implement it?

Comment: i have found what you are looking for not the best approch but it will help you out https://stackoverflow.com/a/57496854/10585521

Comment: the shell process works except that it only opens the host url. For example, if i am trying to search something on google, the url should open the search result. However, using this method, it only manages to open www.google.com. Not the search within google.

Comment: what i the link you want to open ? is there a chance you are are providing the wrong url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NSWorkspace [open method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1535886-open) which has been  deprecated in macOS 11

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!

NSWorkspace.shared.open([url], withAppBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.safari", options: .default, additionalEventParamDescriptor: nil, launchIdentifiers: nil)
```

Or the replacement [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/3172702-open) (macOS 10.15 or later)

```
do {
    let safariURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .applicationDirectory, in: .localDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("Safari.app")
    NSWorkspace.shared.open([url], withApplicationAt: safariURL, configuration: .init()) { (runningApp, error) in
        print("running app", runningApp ?? "nil")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: This solution works fine except that it sometimes opens the link in a new tab and sometimes in a new window entirely. Is there any way to open in a new tab only?

Comment: This is failing for me silently on M1 MacBook Air/Ventura/Xcode 14.3